# How to count the repetitions of a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Unable to get the count value to be correct using the while loop

tried using global variable, but unable to understand its usage and even syntax

tried using the count outside the variable

```py
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20')
selectedNumber=12
while True:
    user_number=int(input("Please enter your number?\n"))
    if user_number<selectedNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low')
        global count=count+1
    elif user_number==selectedNumber:
        break
    else:
        print('Your guess is too high')
print('Great Job', count)
```

Comment: You're only increasing the count when the guess is too low. Just put `count += 1` under the `while True:`

Comment: This is not working and giving a NamError as count is undefined

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you defined count somewhere. Outside the while loop define count : `count = 0` just like you did with `selectedNumber`. In this case you don't need `count` to be global.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest defining the `count` variable outside the loop and then increment that variable every time the loop runs, not inside of the conditions; maybe like this:

```
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20')
selected_number = 12
count = 0

while True:
    user_number = int(input("Please enter your number: "))
    count += 1

    if user_number < selected_number:
        print('Your guess is too low')
    elif user_number == selectedNumber:
        break
    else:
        print('Your guess is too high')

print('Great Job', count)
```